# Small, Vulnerable apps for exploit training

Tags: exploit

I'm looking for some really small apps on Ubuntu for some bufferoverflow exploitation training.

I don't want to start off with some huge apps.

I know some sites like http://www.oldversion.com.de/ where i could start but most of the apps are just to big or too hard to exploit for a beginner or just not available for linux. Most of the tutorial on the Internet or windows based.

Do you know any app where i could start playing around?
Which debugger do usually people use on ubuntu?

As a .NET dev i already have the theoretical knowledge for exploits, but I need to do it myself to understand it better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of apps i think, you can 
get old (vurnable) applications from www.oldapps.com. Then
once there was Damn Vurnable Linux. Or Badstore: www.badstore.net
then we have exploit training: exploit-exercises.com or Pentester
lab: www.pentesterlab.com. Then there is Damn Vurnable webapp:
www.dvwa.co.uk and what i like the most (windows) is vurnable server:
www.thegreycorner.com/p/vulnserver.html‎. Vurnable server you could run
on linux when using wine (did not test this by myself). The debugger of 
choice on Linux Gnu Debugger (gdb www.sourceware.org/gdb/‎). Also in the 
view of the fact that exploits get more and more sophisticated i have to 
mention exploit development is allways hard.

Kind regards,

Dirk

Comment: Thank you very much. Just one more question, and i will accept your answer: Is there a good debugger with a gui like Ollydbg or ummunitydbg for linux & x64 system?

Comment: Hey there no problem, there are some for gdb (afaik is gdb the only really good debugger in linux) it has some front ends like ddd: www.gnu.org/software/ddd/ , you can also use gdb within emacs or eclipse (extra config steps might needed) then there is a terminal interface for gdb http://cgdb.github.io/ . Unfortunaly there are no such pretty debuggers like in windows (i prefer immunitydbg). But this helps at start: http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs107/other/gdbrefcard.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Try going through the extensive list on [OWASP Vulnerable Web Applications Directory Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Vulnerable_Web_Applications_Directory_Project).

Some of them I know and have played with:

- Google Gruyere
- Damn Vunerable App

But some of ASP.NET specific ones include [SPI Dynamics](http://zero.webappsecurity.com/) (live), Watchfire (live), **Acunetix** 2 and 3 (live), **HackmeBank**, and **OWASP SiteGenerator**.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

[Gera’s Insecure Programming](https://github.com/gerasdf/InsecureProgramming) is a classic

It’s somewhat unique in that it includes a few that are either not exploitable, or are only exploitable on certain CPU architectures, which forces you to have a deep understanding of how things work, rather than providing something to copy/paste alephone style payloads in and call it a day

It’s also unique in that it includes more exotic bug classes, like those involving signals